# Java модификаторы доступа

Tags: java, generics

С учебными целями создаю собственные реализации некоторых структур данных. Надо создать обычное бинарное дерево поиска, затем от него унаследовать красно-чёрное и другие самосбалансированные. Для каждого типа дерева есть два класса: собственно дерево и узел (поскольку узлы обычного и красно-чёрного деревьев различаются — второй содержит ещё информацию о цвете). Соответственно просто унаследовать от обычного дерева красно-чёрное не получится.

Я пытаюсь решить это проблему при помощи обобщённых классов. Класс `GenTree` выглядит следующим образом:

```
package BasicTrees;

public abstract class GenTree<KeyType extends Comparable, Type,
        NodeType extends GenNode<KeyType, Type, NodeType>> 
    implements Iterable<NodeType> {

    protected NodeType root;

    protected abstract NodeType newNode(KeyType key, Type value);
    ...
}
```

в этом классе реализованы операции вставки, поиска, удаления, итератор для обычного дерева. Метод `newNode` реализуется уже в каждом конкретном типе дерева, и служит в дальнейшем вместо конструктора для создания новых узлов.
Класс `GenNode` выглядит следующим образом:

```
package BasicTrees;

public class GenNode<KeyType extends Comparable, Type,
            NodeType extends GenNode<KeyType, Type, NodeType>> {

    protected final KeyType key;
    protected Type value;
    protected NodeType left;
    protected NodeType right;
    protected NodeType parent;

    protected GenNode(KeyType key, Type value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

После этого обычное дерево создаётся тривиально классами `Tree`:

```
package BasicTrees;

public class Tree<KeyType extends Comparable, Type>
        extends GenTree<KeyType, Type, Node<KeyType, Type>> {

    @Override
    protected Node<KeyType, Type> newNode(KeyType key, Type value) {
        return new Node<>(key, value);
    }
}
```

и `Node`:

```
package BasicTrees;

public class Node<KeyType extends Comparable, Type>
        extends GenNode<KeyType, Type, Node<KeyType, Type>> {

    protected Node(KeyType key, Type value) {
        super(key, value);
    }
}
```

пакет `BasicTree` также содержит класс `TreeIterator`.

Для создания красно-чёрного и других самосбалансированных деревьев требуется создать отдельный пакет `RBTrees`, чтобы они не путались. Классы `RBTree` и `RBNode` наследуются от `GenTree` и `GenNode` аналогично. В классе `RBNode` добавляется поле, отвечающее за цвет узла. В классе `RBTree` требуется переписать методы, отвечающие за вставку и удаление узлов, метод поиска и итератор остаются теми же. Для этого переписанные методы класса `RBTree` должны иметь доступ к `protected` полям `left`, `right`, `parent`, объявленным в классе `GenNode` и унаследованным `RBNode`. Но модификатор `protected` доступа к ним не даёт, так как `RBTree` не является наследником `GenNode` и не находится с ним в одном пакете.

Можно ли как-то дать доступ к защищённым полям наследников `GenNode` для наследников `GenTree`, не давая его всей программе? Или единственным выходом будет создание в классе `RBNode` геттеров и сеттеров с видимостью пакета, а классе `RBTree` их использовать? Но тогда придётся их создавать каждый раз при создании нового типа дерева. Имеет ли смысл создание этих геттеров и сеттеров с модификатором `protected` в классе `GenNode`? В таком случае они создаются один раз.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества на этот счёт, а также замечания по структуре программы в целом. Был бы рад узнать, можно ли мою задумку реализовать проще.

Спасибо за возможность задать вопрос и подумать над ним в процессе написания. Вариант с геттерами и сеттерами в `GenTree` (который мне кажется оптимальным) я придумал уже в процессе когда писал.

Comment: Как-то все мудрёно.

Comment: Немного не понял, как то всё сложно. Чем отличается красно чёрное дерево от обычного? Это вроде просто нодой и способом хранения данных? Разве не достаточно наследоваться от обычного дерева, и обычной ноды, и переопределить те методы которые различаются?

Comment: Просто унеследовать не получится, потому если наследовать красно-чёрный узел от обычного узла, то его поля left, right, parent по-прежнему будут типа обычного узла. То же самое касается поля root в дереве. Можно, конечно, использовать явное приведение типов, но это небезопасно, придётся всегда явно отслеживать, что в полях left, right, parent содержатся ссылки на объекты нужных классов.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы всё разместил в одном пакете, а классы, связанные с конкретным типом дерева, сделал бы вложенными классами. И активно бы использовал package-private доступ. Именно так реализованы, например, [`HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java) и [`LinkedHashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java) в OpenJDK. Они довольно интенсивно переиспользуют код друг друга, переиспользуемые поля, методы и классы все объявлены package-private.

В целом package-private и организация кода с помощью вложенных классов — это очень хорошо. Не факт, например, что вы вообще хотите выставлять на публику базовый класс `GenTree`. Опубликовав его одиножды, вы навсегда будете привязаны к нему. А вдруг в дальнейшем рефакторинге вы захотите его сильно переделать (например, добавить поддержку небинарных деревьев) или вообще от него отказаться? По большому счёту это деталь реализации. Поэтому его тоже можно сделать package-private.

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж одному типу дерева соответствует один тип узлов, то можно делать конкретную реализацию узла внутренним классом его дерева.

Тогда данный тип дерева будет иметь доступ к его закрытым (private) полям и методам. Узел при этом по-прежнему может наследоваться от абстрактного узла.